# Execlp says No such file or directory

Tags: ps, execl

I am trying to do `ps -A` in code, but typing `execlp("/bin/ps", "ps", "-A", NULL);` outputs:

`/bin/ps: No such file or directory`

But I can see ps in the file directory so I have no idea what is wrong.